# JSON Schema away to specify an "any"-type schema with certain required fields

Tags: json, jsonschema

Let's say I have the following JSON Schema

```
{
 "name":"Product",
 "type":"object",
 "properties":{
   "id":{
     "type":"number",
     "required":true
   },
   "name":{
     "description":"Name of the product",
     "required":true
   },
   "price":{
     "required":true,
     "type": "number",
     "minimum":0,
     "required":true
   },
   "tags":{
     "type":"array",
     "items":{
       "type":"any"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

But, instead of tags being an array, I'd like it to be part of the root schema. So you could specify any property, but I give special attention to "id", "name" and "price"
Which of the following would be the correct way of doing it, and which ones are completely wrong?

```
{
 "name":"Product",
 "type":"object",
 "properties":{
   "id":{
     "type":"number",
     "required":true
   },
   "name":{
     "description":"Name of the product",
     "required":true
   },
   "price":{
     "required":true,
     "type": "number",
     "minimum":0,
     "required":true
   }
 },
 "additionalProperties": {
     "type":"any"
 }
}

{
 "name":"Product",
 "type":"object",
 "properties":{
   "id":{
     "type":"number",
     "required":true
   },
   "name":{
     "description":"Name of the product",
     "required":true
   },
   "price":{
     "required":true,
     "type": "number",
     "minimum":0,
     "required":true
   }
 },
 "extends": {
     "type":"any"
 }
}

{
 "name":"Product",
 "type":["object","any"],
 "properties":{
   "id":{
     "type":"number",
     "required":true
   },
   "name":{
     "description":"Name of the product",
     "required":true
   },
   "price":{
     "required":true,
     "type": "number",
     "minimum":0,
     "required":true
   }
 }
}
```

I can come up with a few more (such as inverting roles of "any" and "object"), but they are all derivative of these three examples.

Answer (score 37):

[disclaimer: author of the next JSON Schema validation spec here]

OK, it is unclear what you ask, see below, but one of your examples clearly does not do what you want, this is the one where you write:

```
{ "type": [ "object", "any" ] }
```

This is equivalent to an empty schema, and as such validates each and every instance.

One way I read your question is that you want your JSON data to be either a tag array or an object with at least members named `id`, `name` and `price`. Since you seem to be using draft v3, you only have one solution:

```
{
    "type": [
        {
            "description": "schema for tags array here",
        },
        {
            "description": "schema for the base object here"
        }
    ]
}
```

This construct means that the instance must obey at least one schema inside `type` (and you can mix it with primitive types as well).

**However**: the current draft now being v4, you should now write:

```
{
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "description": "schema for tags array here",
        },
        {
            "description": "schema for the base object here"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that not all implementations support draft v4, or the construct for `type` above. In fact, very few do. See below for a link to an online schema validator which supports both.

Another way that I read your question is that you want to allow properties other than `id`, `name` and `price` to be whatever they like. This is then quite simple. Just don't define a schema for `tags` in `properties`:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "id", "name", "price" ]
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "name": {
            "description": "Name of the product"
        },
        "price": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Since you don't specify `additionalProperties` as being `false`, the object instance can have any number of additional members, and these members can be anything.

Link to an online validator which can test your schemas: [here](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com)

Comment: This was very helpful, I didn't realize that you could define multiple possible type values. (Yeah, newb at json schemas here.)

Comment: And, errr, what do you want to do, then? You still did not really tell ;)

Comment: I didn't really say anything, it wasn't my question. I just happened to show up thanks to Google. If you're curious, though, I was trying to handle the case when the API I'm getting JSON from sends me an object some of the time and an integer other times, but I still want one of those two and not "any".

Comment: You can post a message to the JSON Schema google group, they'll help you make your schema ;)

Comment: Sorry being late on this, but you have answered my question and then some. Brilliant. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: @fge what if my schema element can either be an array or null? If I try writing null, it gives me an error: 
"found null, expected one of [array, string]"

Comment: @amey91 a null value in JSON Schema is `"type": "null"`, or, if in an enum, the value null: `{ "enum": [ null ] }`

Comment: @fge TY! I was using null without quotation marks and that was causing the error